# Change the image source in anchor tag using pure javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

How can I change the image source which is embeded in anchor tag.

Here is the code.

```
 <body class="home">
   <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-          
       uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png"/></a
  </body>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: am trying through

Comment: am trying through    document.getelementbyclassName but am not able to get how to combile both get elementbyclassname and tagname

Comment: use an id for `img` tag

Comment: Right now I cant use its in wordpress so I need to do it through javascript

Comment: on which condition you want to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].children[0].src="http://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"
```

without using any id
i have created a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/f3rdnzgt/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="newimage.jpg" onclick="this.children[0].src = this.href; return false;" class="logo"><img src="oldimage.jpg"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to `img` tag , then use following code.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("newImage").src="newImagepath/newimage.jpg";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this img tag an id then use

```
 document.getElementById(id).src = "newimagesource.png" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `querySelector` like this -

```
document.querySelector(".logo img").src = "your new src";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="home">
   <a href="#" class="logo"><img id ="picture" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-          
       uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png"/></a
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementsById("picture").setAttribute("src", "New_image_path");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The smallest way for doing it is

```
document.querySelector(".logo img").src = "new_source";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just assign the id attribute to the image and change the source, 
for your case:
```

```html
<body class="home" onload="changethesrc('newimagescr.png')">
        <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-          
       uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" id="imageid"/></a
       </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
       function changethesrc(newsrc){
   var tmpimg = document.getElementById("imageid");

  tmpimg.src = newsrc;
       }
         </script>
```